# What is the meaning of var something: (() -> Void)? in Swift

Tags: swift

Just reading through some docs I see declarations like this

```
  var loginSuccess: (() -> Void)?
```

throughout the code, I was wondering what this is called and what it's use case would be?

In this example I see

```
loginVC.loginSuccess = {
    self.activityIndicator.startAnimating()
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true) {
        self.viewModel.fetchThreats()
    }
}
```

So I'm assuming it's just a closure that be invoked when an action completes. Returns nothing and accepts nothing?

Comment: That's what it looks like to me.

Comment: Please read the [Closures](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html) chapter in the Swift book.

Comment: As said by rmaddy, the keyword you miss is `Closure`. It's also called "Block" in Objective-C.

Comment: An *optional* closer that takes and returns nothing, correct.